# Add new line from parsed xml string

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am parsing a xml file in which it has a long paragraph, I am trying to add a new line through the xml file. I tried adding \r to the xml file but it just prints it to the textview.

For example I am getting data like:

*

> Price: $100
>  Manufacturer: Apple

*

.... And so on.

But instead it shows:

*

> Price: $100 \r Manufacturer: Apple \r

*

Where it parses the tag:

```
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"thedescription"])
        {
            NSString *trimmed = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

            currentCommunity.commDescription = trimmed;
            currentNodeContent = nil;

    }
```

I have also tried using a `<br />` tag but that didn't work it just didn't show the tag.
How can I get it to make a new line in the textview from data entered in the xml file under one tag?

like so:

*

> Price: $100 \r Manufacturer: Apple \r

*

Your help is appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you show your iOS code?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor edited with more code

Comment: Did you try `\n` ( which stands for new line ) ? By the way, does your text view has multi line?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor yes I did with no luck. It just prints it to the textview.

Answer (score 0):

So what I did was I had to replace characters in the text with \n, you can't replace \n with \n or anything that uses a slash (). So what I did is in the xml file where I wanted a new line I added `*br*` and had it replace it with \n:

```
if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"thedescription"])
        {
            NSString *trimmed = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
            trimmed = [trimmed stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*br*" withString:@"\n"];
            currentCommunity.commDescription = trimmed;
            currentNodeContent = nil;

    }
```

And it works just fine, although I would suggest to parse it as it is and when you are displaying it to replace `*br*` with \n so that you could use the string somewhere else without the new line, in my case:

```
currentCommunity.commDescription = [currentCommunity.commDescription stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*br*" withString:@""];
```

Now that string can be used in the app anywhere without the `*br*` appearing.